# Can I run an SQL update statement using only dplyr syntax in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, rpostgresql, r-dbi

I need to update column values conditionnaly on other columns in some `PostgreSQL` database table. I managed to do it writing an SQL statement in R and executing it with `dbExecute` from `DBI` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

# Establish connection with database
con <- dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), dbname = "myDb",
                 host="localhost", port= 5432, user="me",password = myPwd)

# Write SQL update statement
request <- paste("UPDATE table_to_update",
                 "SET var_to_change = 'new value' ",
                 "WHERE filter_var = 'filter' ")

# Back-end execution
con %>% dbExecute(request)
```

Is it possible to do so using only `dplyr` syntax ? I tried, out of curiosity,

```
con %>% tbl("table_to_update") %>%
   mutate(var_to_change = if (filter_var == 'filter') 'new value' else var_to_change)
```

which works in R but obviously does nothing in db since it uses a `select` statement. `copy_to` allows only for `append` and `overwite` options, so I can't see how to use it unless deleting then appending the filtered observations...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current dplyr 0.7.1 (with dbplyr 1.1.0) doesn't support this, because it assumes that all data sources are immutable. Issuing an `UPDATE` via `dbExecute()` seems to be the best bet.

For replacing a larger chunk in a table, you could also:

1. Write the data frame to a temporary table in the database via `copy_to()`.
2. Start a transaction.
3. Issue a `DELETE FROM ... WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM <temporary table>)`
4. Issue an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM <temporary table>`
5. Commit the transaction

Depending on your schema, you might be able to do a single `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` instead of `DELETE` and then `INSERT`.

Comment: How about using `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`? And in this way, we can ignore the third step of `DELETE` relevant rows from the table.

Comment: I think the syntax might be slightly different in PostgreSQL, but I'm not sure. For other databases this might work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have tested to use `REPLACE INTO` in `SQLite`, which works well. Thanks for your comment. @krlmlr